# How to render dust template with backbone

Tags: backbone.js, dust.js

I'm trying to display a dust template (compiled) within a backbone view.

here is my render function in the view :

```
render: ->
  dust.render("customer-item", @model.toJSON(), (err, output) ->
    throw err if err
    $(@el).html output
  )
  @
```

When i lead the view i see 2 divs added inside my container (corresponding to the 2 models that should be loaded) but they are both empty.  The individual template is not redered...
When I debug the "output" variable i see the template so in theory it should be loaded properly...

When I do a simple test **I can see an output** for :

```
render: ->
      $(@el).html "<span>TEST</span>"
      @
```

But for that scenario **I have no output** :

```
render: ->
      dust.render("customer-item", @model.toJSON(), (err, output) ->
        $(@el).html "<span>TEST</span>"
      )
      @
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't used Dust that much but for what I remember you should compile your template first like that (in plain Javascript):

```
var source   = $("#some-template").html();
var compiled = dust.compile(source,"table"); 

dust.loadSource(compiled);

dust.render("table",this.model.toJSON(),function(err,out){
    $(el).html(out);
});
```

**EDIT:**

I think I found where the problem lies: when you call `$(this.el).html(out)` inside your dust.render function, `this` is out of context. So you have to change your render function to something like that:

```
var self = this;
dust.render("table",this.model.toJSON(),function(err,out){
    $(self.el).html(out);
});
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your answer. I forgot to mention that my template is already compiled on the server side.  I m using node.js with duster.js like explained on this blog : http://dmix.ca/2011/12/dustjs-backbonejs-dusterjs/.  If I compile the template on the client side, I will loose all the potentials of dustjs.  Any ideas are welcome...

Comment: Sorry but I don't know much about the approach you are following... if you debug the output variable what did you see? the template compiled with your model's data or just a raw template?

Comment: I see the template with the model's data. What happen I don't know... I see 2 divs injected but nothing inside. Maybe my el element is not correct but how do I know that?

Comment: Well inside you render function you can comment the dust's render function and just write `$(@el).html("<span>TEST</span>")` to see if it's actually dyst's fault. How do you declare el in your view anyway?

Comment: Outside the `dust.render` function i have an output but inside for the same test `$(@el).html "<span>TEST</span>"` i have no output.  Why I don't know...

Comment: Check my edit to my answer and let me know if it may help you!

Comment: Hi thanks, you find my mistake, it was simply a context scope issue... Many thanks for your time and your knowledge !

Answer (score 1):

As @Ingro explained this is an issue the this (@) context.

An option is to assign the this to a local variable (like "self" or "that")

```
render: ->
  self = @
  dust.render("customer-item", @model.toJSON(), (err, output) ->
    throw err if err
    self.$el.html output
  )
  @
```

Another option is to use CoffeeScript's "=>" (fat arrow)

```
render: ->
  dust.render("customer-item", @model.toJSON(), (err, output) =>
    throw err if err
    @$el.html output
  )
  @
```